# How to keep XMPP connection alive in the IOS App when app in background?

Tags: ios, swift2, xmpp, openfire, xcode7.2

I have create basic chat app with XMPP Server in swift 2 (from this tutorial: `http://shubhank101.github.io/iOSAndroidChaosOverFlow/2016/08/Chat-Application-Using-XMPP-Swift-Tutorial`). My app is working good. but when my app went into background then my app unable to receive any message from XMPP server. i think this is because of XMPP connection break while entering the app in background.

i have tried to found the help on google for the same but nothing found related to `Swift 2`

Please help me. if some one put some sample code that would very helpfull for me because i m new to IOS development.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Third-party apps on the iOS are not allowed to keep network connection in background. See [Apple guidelines](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/Performance/Conceptual/EnergyGuide-iOS/EnergyandNetworking.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40015243-CH16-SW1) how to avoid background networking.

Comment: thanks for your comment. but we can perform some background process in ios and i m looking for that like: https://www.raywenderlich.com/143128/background-modes-tutorial-getting-started

Comment: Allowed background modes are for short finite tasks, all of them are not suitable for persistent network connection.

Answer (score 0):

You need to create a background thread to maintain XMPP connection. You can follow this tutorial to see how background thread works. https://thatthinginswift.com/background-threads/